# Navigating Quicktime chapters with Javascript

Tags: javascript, quicktime

I am trying to use javascript to navigate chapters in Quicktime videos.

I am able to see how many chapters are in each Quicktime with this function:

```
   function GetChapterCount(anObj)
   {
     return anObj.GetChapterCount();
   }
```

and this href:

```
<a href="javascript:alert(GetChapterCount(document.movie1));">
     Chapter Count</a><br>
```

I can also get the name of each chapter with this function:

```
    function GetChapterName(anObj)
   {
     return anObj.GetChapterName(3);
   }
```

and this href:

```
<a href="javascript:alert(GetChapterName(document.movie1));">
     Chapter 3 Name</a><br>
```

I can also manually jump to a chapter with this href:

```
<a href="javascript:document.movie1.GoToChapter('Chapter3Name');">
     Goto Chapter 3</a><br>
```

My problem is I have to manually type each chapters name.  I want to be able to read the chapter name from the Quicktime and pass that to the GoToChapter, but I have not been able to figure that out yet.

I am sure there is an easy way to make a function that passes the ChapterName to GoToChapter.

Thanks,
Dusty

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out.  First I created this function

```
    function Chapter1Name(anObj)
   {
     return anObj.GetChapterName(1);
   }
```

Then I called it with this href

```
<a href="javascript:document.movie1.GoToChapter(Chapter1Name(document.movie1));">
     Goto Chapter 1</a><br>
```

If there is a better way, please let me know.

Thanks,
Dusty